# Trouble with Piwik API URL

Tags: matomo

I'm trying to make an application to get data from the Piwik API to process and analyse. I'm having trouble getting the API URL to work properly for our specific site (our Piwik is a multi-site installation, our site is identified by a segment variable, specifically customVariableValue1=9).

(I've replaced our domain and token with placeholders)
This URL works fine: 
https://example.com/piwik/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=3&date=yesterday&period=day&format=json&token_auth=mytoken

However when I try to access this:
https://example.com/piwik/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=3&date=yesterday&period=day&%20segment=customVariableValue1%3D%3D9#&format=json&token_auth=mytoken

I get this error: `<error message="You can't access this resource as it requires an 'view' access for the website id = 3."/>` back. The token I am using is definitely correct so I have no idea why it's coming back with that error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `token_auth` after `#` sign so it is interpreted as fragment identifier, not as part of query.

This URL should be valid:

https://example.com/piwik/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=3&date=yesterday&period=day&format=json&token_auth=mytoken&segment=customVariableValue1%3D%3D9#